# Cruelty free protein enhanced milk for cats to base their diet on

Tags: vegetarian-diet, animal-welfare, lacto-ovo-vegetarianism, lacto-vegetarianism, milk

Is it possible to add vegan or vegetarian derived protein supplements to milk to give them the strength of a meat substitute suitable for cat diets. It, would be such, that the cat can base their entire diet on these protein enhanced milks.

This, works make cats, and cat people strong.

Comment: cow milk is meant to be consumed by baby cows, not anything else

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you want to feed cow's milk to a cat that's not a baby.

It's very easy (and cheap) to feed cats [adequate protein](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/a/58/4031).

The only hard part of feeding a cat a vegan diet is the additives, which [you have to buy](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/a/2740/4031).

Comment: +1 ... even baby cats, just like baby humans, shouldn't drink cow's milk, as it doesn't meet their specific nutritional needs (see for example https://www.petmd.com/cat/nutrition/can-cats-drink-milk <-- maybe a useful read for you Joselin Jocklingson)