# How to access cat meat from animals that were not killed

Tags: ethics, animal-welfare

What would be the problem with feeding cats with only meat from dead carcasses from animals that aged and then died of a natural death (i.e., the meat, would be, only from animals that are not killed).

I do not see a problem with this. So why isn't cat food labeled this way.

Where can I buy such cat food.

I want to love my cat, and I would be able to love it better, if, it are, meat from dead carcasses that died of a natural death.

I feel that this would also be more in line with veganism and vegetarianism.

Answer (score 3):

What did the animal die of though?

If it's a disease then you'd have to hope it's not one that can transmit to your cat (or from your cat to you). Some diseases such as [tuberculosis](https://www.daera-ni.gov.uk/articles/what-bovine-tuberculosis-tb) can transmit cross-species for instance.

If not and it died of old age, how long has it been dead before it's turned into cat food? If it died in a field somewhere several days ago then the processes of decay will have started and it wouldn't seem like a good idea to feed your cat meat filled with maggots. So you'd need some mechanism to watch each animal in real time for its entire life. I'm not sure how you'd do that since I'm sure you're not suggesting keeping each animal in a small cage and/or inserting some kind of monitoring device into them.

Answer (score 1):

[Seitan](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/a/58/4031) is much higher in protein than dead animals.

It's trivial (and cheap) to [make "meat" for cats](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/a/2740/4031) from wheat gluten.

Comment: I've tried giving my cat vegetarian meal made from milk and eggs, but my cat won't eat it. Why?

Comment: @JoselinJocklingson cats are picky. You have to gradually transition them. First add just one teaspoon of vegan cat food to whatever they like eating now. Over many months, adjust the ratio until you're feeding them just one teaspoon of their old food with mostly the new food. Finally, stop buying the old food.

Comment: Also, why are you expecting an adult cat to eat milk or eggs? Make them [cat food](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/a/2740/4031)